# Documenting Iterable<T> using Springfox swagger with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, springfox

I have a pretty simple Spring Boot REST API using Spring Data. This is my Repository:

```java
public interface TodoRepository extends CrudRepository<Todo, Integer> {}
```

Here is my controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/todos")
public class TodosController {
    @Autowired
    private TodoRepository todoRepository;

    @PostMapping(path = "")
    public Todo addTodo(@RequestParam String content) {
        Todo todo = new Todo();
        todo.setContent(content);
        todo.setDone(false);
        return todoRepository.save(todo);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "")
    public Iterable<Todo> findAll() {
        return todoRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

When I use springfox to generate swagger docs, pretty much every thing looks fine except the `findAll` endpoint. The response model is documented as an empty object `{}` instead of an Array of `Todo`.

[image: Incorrect model]

However when I use a `List<T>` instead of the default `Iterable<T>` provided by the repository, by adding the following to my controller:

```java
    ...
    @GetMapping(path = "/asList")
    public List<Todo> asList() {
        var result = new ArrayList<Todo>();
        todoRepository.findAll().forEach(result::add);
        return result;
    }
```

Then it shows up correctly.

[image: Correct model]

Is there a way I can get the same behavior for the default `Iterable<T>` that the repository returns so that I wouldn't have to convert to a `List<T>` every time?

Comment: I'd file it as a bug on SpringFox.

Comment: I'm still seeing this behavior in June, 2022. Was there ever a bug created or any resolution?

Comment: I found [this bug](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3371) and this [other bug](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3022), but the "explanation" isn't clear to me how one can work around this unfortunate limitation.